# Hosting an external CMS like WordPress on a Django powered site

Tags: python, django, wordpress, content-management-system

I have a Django powered website called `mysite.com` and would like to use an external CMS like WordPress blog that can be accessed at `blog.mysite.com`. Since I am a noob to CMS, I have a few questions -

1. Is the above thing possible?
2. Where should the `blog.mysite.com` be hosted? I think it would be a bad idea to host it on the same web server as `mysite.com`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes it is possible, and in fact, common.
2. You can host it on the same server, or a different one. How this would work really depends on your hosting environment. For example, I have a VPS with the ability to directly modify Apache virtual host config files. If I wanted to use the same server to host both sites, I'd simply setup another virtual host configuration.

**My Two Cents**

Recently, I've spent a lot of time cleaning up a compromised WordPress site. For that reason alone, I'm glad the WordPress site is on a different server than our Django application. Your domain name registrar most likely has a DNS settings page that would allow you to direct traffic for various subdomains to different server IP's of your choosing.

Also, have you considered integrating a Django-based CMS like [django-cms](http://www.django-cms.org/en/)?